# Is it possible to get monthly historical stock prices in python?

Tags: python, pandas, quantitative-finance

I know using pandas this is how you normally get daily stock price quotes. But I'm wondering if its possible to get monthly or weekly quotes, is there maybe a parameter I can pass through to get monthly quotes?

```
    from pandas.io.data import DataReader
    from datetime import datetime

    ibm = DataReader('IBM',  'yahoo', datetime(2000,1,1), datetime(2012,1,1))
    print(ibm['Adj Close'])
```

Comment: No, there is not a way.

Answer (score 11):

Monthly closing prices from Yahoo! Finance...

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web

data = web.get_data_yahoo('IBM','01/01/2015',interval='m')
```

where you can replace the interval input as required ('d', 'w', 'm', etc).

Comment: Great answer! Unfortunately i didn't see it before... +1

Comment: I think you might be better off resampling the data after you get it. Using the monthly interval interpolates data for the first of every month. You can first download your daily data and then:  [code] data = data.resample('BM').last() OR .first() [/code]

Answer (score 4):

Using Yahoo Finance, it is possible to get Stock Prices using "interval" option with instead of "m" as shown:

```
 #Library
    import yfinance as yf    
    from datetime import datetime
    
 #Load Stock price
    df = yf.download("IBM", start= datetime(2000,1,1), end = datetime(2012,1,1),interval='1mo')
    df
```

The result is:
[image: IBM Stock Price between 01-01-2000 and 01-01-2012]

The other possible interval options are:

- 1m,
- 2m,
- 5m,
- 15m,
- 30m,
- 60m,
- 90m,
- 1h,
- 1d,
- 5d,
- 1wk,
- 1mo,
- 3mo.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
In [175]: from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader

In [176]: ibm = DataReader('IBM',  'yahoo', '2001-01-01', '2012-01-01')
```

**UPDATE:** show average for `Adj Close` only (month start)

```
In [12]: ibm.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='MS'))['Adj Close'].mean()
Out[12]:
Date
2001-01-01     79.430605
2001-02-01     86.625519
2001-03-01     75.938913
2001-04-01     81.134375
2001-05-01     90.460754
2001-06-01     89.705042
2001-07-01     83.350254
2001-08-01     82.100543
2001-09-01     74.335789
2001-10-01     79.937451
                 ...
2011-03-01    141.628553
2011-04-01    146.530774
2011-05-01    150.298053
2011-06-01    146.844772
2011-07-01    158.716834
2011-08-01    150.690990
2011-09-01    151.627555
2011-10-01    162.365699
2011-11-01    164.596963
2011-12-01    167.924676
Freq: MS, Name: Adj Close, dtype: float64
```

show average for Adj Close only (month end)

```
In [13]: ibm.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M'))['Adj Close'].mean()
Out[13]:
Date
2001-01-31     79.430605
2001-02-28     86.625519
2001-03-31     75.938913
2001-04-30     81.134375
2001-05-31     90.460754
2001-06-30     89.705042
2001-07-31     83.350254
2001-08-31     82.100543
2001-09-30     74.335789
2001-10-31     79.937451
                 ...
2011-03-31    141.628553
2011-04-30    146.530774
2011-05-31    150.298053
2011-06-30    146.844772
2011-07-31    158.716834
2011-08-31    150.690990
2011-09-30    151.627555
2011-10-31    162.365699
2011-11-30    164.596963
2011-12-31    167.924676
Freq: M, Name: Adj Close, dtype: float64
```

monthly averages (all columns):

```
In [179]: ibm.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).mean()
Out[179]:
                  Open        High         Low       Close    Volume   Adj Close
Date
2001-01-31  100.767857  103.553571   99.428333  101.870357   9474409   79.430605
2001-02-28  111.193160  113.304210  108.967368  110.998422   8233626   86.625519
2001-03-31   97.366364   99.423637   95.252272   97.281364  11570454   75.938913
2001-04-30  103.990500  106.112500  102.229501  103.936999  11310545   81.134375
2001-05-31  115.781363  117.104091  114.349091  115.776364   7243463   90.460754
2001-06-30  114.689524  116.199048  113.739523  114.777618   6806176   89.705042
2001-07-31  106.717143  108.028095  105.332857  106.646666   7667447   83.350254
2001-08-31  105.093912  106.196521  103.856522  104.939999   6234847   82.100543
2001-09-30   95.138667   96.740000   93.471334   94.987333  12620833   74.335789
2001-10-31  101.400870  103.140000  100.327827  102.145217   9754413   79.937451
2001-11-30  113.449047  114.875715  112.510952  113.938095   6435061   89.256046
2001-12-31  120.651001  122.076000  119.790500  121.087999   6669690   94.878736
2002-01-31  116.483334  117.509524  114.613334  115.994762   9217280   90.887920
2002-02-28  103.194210  104.389474  101.646316  102.961579   9069526   80.764672
2002-03-31  105.246500  106.764499  104.312999  105.478499   7563425   82.756873
...                ...         ...         ...         ...       ...         ...
2010-10-31  138.956188  140.259048  138.427142  139.631905   6537366  122.241844
2010-11-30  144.281429  145.164762  143.385241  144.439524   4956985  126.878319
2010-12-31  145.155909  145.959545  144.567273  145.251819   4245127  127.726929
2011-01-31  152.595000  153.950499  151.861000  153.181501   5941580  134.699880
2011-02-28  163.217895  164.089474  162.510002  163.339473   4687763  144.050847
2011-03-31  160.433912  161.745652  159.154349  160.425651   5639752  141.628553
2011-04-30  165.437501  166.587500  164.760500  165.978500   5038475  146.530774
2011-05-31  169.657144  170.679046  168.442858  169.632857   5276390  150.298053
2011-06-30  165.450455  166.559093  164.691819  165.593635   4792836  146.844772
2011-07-31  178.124998  179.866502  177.574998  178.981500   5679660  158.716834
2011-08-31  169.734350  171.690435  166.749567  169.360434   8480613  150.690990
2011-09-30  169.752858  172.034761  168.109999  170.245714   6566428  151.627555
2011-10-31  181.529525  183.597145  180.172379  182.302381   6883985  162.365699
2011-11-30  184.536668  185.950952  182.780477  184.244287   4619719  164.596963
2011-12-31  188.151428  189.373809  186.421905  187.789047   4925547  167.924676

[132 rows x 6 columns]
```

weekly averages (all columns):

```
In [180]: ibm.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='W')).mean()
Out[180]:
                  Open        High         Low       Close    Volume   Adj Close
Date
2001-01-07   89.234375   94.234375   87.890625   91.656250  11060200   71.466436
2001-01-14   93.412500   95.062500   91.662500   93.412500   7470200   72.835824
2001-01-21  100.250000  103.921875   99.218750  102.250000  13851500   79.726621
2001-01-28  109.575000  111.537500  108.675000  110.600000   8056720   86.237303
2001-02-04  113.680000  115.465999  111.734000  113.582001   6538080   88.562436
2001-02-11  113.194002  115.815999  111.639999  113.884001   7269320   88.858876
2001-02-18  113.960002  116.731999  113.238000  115.106000   7225420   89.853021
2001-02-25  109.525002  111.375000  105.424999  107.977501  10722700   84.288436
2001-03-04  103.390001  106.052002  100.386000  103.228001  11982540   80.580924
2001-03-11  105.735999  106.920000  103.364002  104.844002   9226900   81.842391
2001-03-18   95.660001   97.502002   93.185997   94.899998  13863740   74.079992
2001-03-25   90.734000   92.484000   88.598000   90.518001  11382280   70.659356
2001-04-01   95.622000   97.748000   94.274000   96.106001  10467580   75.021411
2001-04-08   95.259999   97.360001   93.132001   94.642000  12312580   73.878595
2001-04-15   98.350000   99.520000   95.327502   97.170000  10218625   75.851980
...                ...         ...         ...         ...       ...         ...
2011-09-25  170.678003  173.695996  169.401996  171.766000   6358100  152.981582
2011-10-02  176.290002  178.850000  174.729999  176.762000   7373680  157.431216
2011-10-09  175.920001  179.200003  174.379999  177.792001   7623560  158.348576
2011-10-16  185.366000  187.732001  184.977997  187.017999   5244180  166.565614
2011-10-23  180.926001  182.052002  178.815997  180.351999   9359200  160.628611
2011-10-30  183.094003  184.742001  181.623996  183.582001   5743800  163.505379
2011-11-06  184.508002  186.067999  183.432004  184.716003   4583780  164.515366
2011-11-13  185.350000  186.690002  183.685999  185.508005   4180620  165.750791
2011-11-20  187.600003  189.101999  185.368002  186.738000   5104420  166.984809
2011-11-27  181.067497  181.997501  178.717499  179.449997   4089350  160.467733
2011-12-04  185.246002  187.182001  184.388000  186.052002   5168720  166.371376
2011-12-11  191.841998  194.141998  191.090002  192.794000   4828580  172.400204
2011-12-18  191.085999  191.537998  187.732001  188.619998   6037220  168.667729
2011-12-25  183.810001  184.634003  181.787997  183.678000   5433360  164.248496
2012-01-01  185.140003  185.989998  183.897499  184.750000   3029925  165.207100

[574 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: Hey that's great you can do it with the mean when I don't add .mean() i get this response  

        ibm.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M'))

        <pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x00000000078583C8>


How can I get soely the price for those month

Answer (score 1):

Get it from Quandl:

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'  # Optional
quandl.ApiConfig.api_version = '2015-04-09'  # Optional

ibm = quandl.get("WIKI/IBM", start_date="2000-01-01", end_date="2012-01-01", collapse="monthly", returns="pandas")
```

Comment: can I do a bulk download, where I pass in a list of stocks and get those prices?